# Difference between showing there is at least one periodic solution and showing that all solutions are periodic

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, periodic-functions

Suppose that a system of differential equations is given in the following form
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = Ay(x) + b(x)$$
with $A$ a matrix. If $y(x)$ is a general solution, what is the difference between showing  there is at least one periodic solution and showing that all solutions are periodic?

Answer (score 0):

Assume there exists a periodic solution $y_1(x)$ and a non-periodic solution $y_2(x)$. Then the first statement is true and the second is false.

Or assume there is no solution at all. Then the first statement is false and the second is true.

Comment: But how to show that there exists at least one periodic solution? And how to show that all solutions are periodic?